# issues accessing variable in parent from child - flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Im trying to access some variables from the parent in a child mc.

Parent code:

```
var date_1:String;
var date_2:String;
var date_3:String;


date_1 = "test1";
date_2 = "test2";
date_3 = "test3";
```

Child code:

```
date_1_txt.text = MovieClip(parent).date_1;
date_2_txt.text = MovieClip(parent).date_2;
date_3_txt.text = MovieClip(parent).date_3;
```

I keep getting the output error:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter text must be non-null.
    at flash.text::TextField/set text()
    at fi_fla::Symbol2_2/frame1()
```

nothing shows up in any of the dynamic text fields...

any ideas?

Comment: This seems like a poor practice - it would be better for the parent to pass values to the child or both to share a model.

Comment: I'm not looking to go to technical in this project. this method has worked fine before, and will do fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that date_1 is a null value.

There are two possibilities:

- date_1 is not defined
- date_1 never got assigned a String value (uninitialized String vars have the value null)

Maybe the code in the child gets called before the code in the parent?